# render leaflet map inside div in background and in foreground a name div

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework

i have a leaflet map, which i placed in a div tag, in now i want to put a component i created in the foreground, but this does not work. i see that the self created component is generated behind the leaflet map. i tried to apply the position absolute and releative, as well as the z-index. however, this did not help either. do you have any other solutions?

id click has to be in the foreground!

```
<div id="mapId">

    <app-click (os)="recive($event)" id="click">
    </app-click>

</div>
```

```
#mapId{

  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#click{
  z-index: 100;
  //position: fixed;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: You should try to apply a higher z-index value to the #click element instead of the #dynamic element. Also, make sure that the #click element has a position property set to absolute or fixed.